# For loop speed performance in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, performance

I went throught http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHtdZgou0qU speed up your javascript.

So i did this personal speed test:

```
    var count = 50000000;
    var testDummy;

    // test 1
    testDummy = 0;
    var test1Start = new Date().getTime();
    var i;
    for (i=0;i<count;i++) {
        testDummy++;
    }
    var test1End = new Date().getTime();
    var test1Total = (test1End-test1Start);

    // test 2
    testDummy = 0;
    var test2Start = new Date().getTime();
    var i
    for (i=count; i--;) {
        testDummy++;
    }
    var test2End = new Date().getTime();
    var test2Total = (test2End-test2Start);


    debug(
      "test1\n" + 
      "total: " + test1Total + "\n" + 
      "test2\n" + 
      "total: " + test2Total 
    );
```

I get not significant results, like sometimes they are even and sometimes not.

My question is, if i use for loop like this: "`for(i=count;i--;)`" is it really faster ?
Am i doing something wrong in my tests.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you got something wrong here, `for(i=count;i--;)` doesn't make any sense...

Comment: Sorry, it does make sense (when it reaches 0 casts to false)... however I don't see how this could be faster

Comment: I suppose the idea is that instead of executing two statements per loop iteration (test, increment) you can combine the increment step into the test step and execute only one statement per iteration...

Comment: The 3rd arguments is absent so the usual operation time is skipped, and the 2nd argument is faster since there is not operator comparaison. I mean that usually if you do as a 2nd arg, i<length, then it compares i with length, then it compares the result with false to stop the for loop. In this case there is only one comparaison with false, if 'i' is 0 then it is automatically false.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you may be more likely to get that optimization using predecrement instead of postdecrement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'd write this as a comment, but it'd be too long.)

First: Worrying about the efficiency of a `for` loop is almost always a waste of (your own) time. What's inside of the loop usually has much more impact on performance than the details of how the loop is specified.

Second: What browser(s) did you test with? Different browsers will show different performance profiles; even different versions of the same browser will differ.

Third: It's not out of the question that the JavaScript engine optimized your loops out of the picture. A JavaScript compiler could simply look at the loop and decide to set `testDummy` to 50000000 and be done with it.

Fourth: If you really want to split hairs on performance, I'd try `for(i=count; --i != 0;)` as well as `for(i=count;i--;)`. The former may save a machine instruction or two, because executing the subtraction (in the predecrement step) may automatically set a hardware flag indicating that the result was 0. That flag is potentially wasted when you're using the postdecrement operator, because it wouldn't be examined until the start of the next iteration. (The chances that you'd be able to notice the difference are slim to none.)

Comment: I test with Firefox, Chrome, Internet explorer 8 and safari. thanks for the comment/answer. I need to proces bunch of data and it as to be lightning fast. So performance gain is important event for 50ms-150ms.

Comment: @developer: how much data are you really dealing with?

Comment: well, i'm manipulating around 200 to 500 string element (words) and make combinaison of words in many differents way, and then count frequency of each combinaison (you can compare it as a tagcloud). I build arrays for combinaison of multiples size (2-tuples, 3-tuples, etc.)

Comment: @developerGuile: Then instead of agonizing over the `for` loop, you'd be far better off thinking about how to do the string manipulation most efficiently. Any `for` loop optimization you employ is unlikely to be noticeable when compared to the time used in the string manipulations. (If you find otherwise, I'd **really** like to hear about it!)

Answer (score 3):

Well...

```
for( i=0 ; i < len ; i++ )
```

is practically the same as

```
for( i = len ; i-- ; )
```

Lets describe it:

**case 1:**
let i be 0
boolean expression
let i be i + 1

**case 2:**
let i be len
let i be i - 1
cast i to boolean (type coersion) and interpret it.

The difference should be minute and depends entirely on how efficient type coersion is compared to a normal boolean expression.

Incidentally, test this:]

```
var i = count;
while( i-- ) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your tests.

The blocks that you are testing are very-near identical, meaning the difference in execution speeds are going to be trivial. In both examples, a variable (i) is set to a fixed value and looped until it reaches a fixed value (count). The only thing that differs is i++ and i--, which in terms of speed, I think are practically the same.

The thing you have to be careful of (not do) is calculate the "loop until" value inside the loop definition.

Comment: I'm trying to gain speed by skipping the 3rd argument and taking out a comparison step in the 2nd argument. That is what Nicholas C. Zakas talks about in his youtube video but can't reproduce a test to see the gain by myself.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some tests too, here are the results.

In many articles, books authors propose that "optimized" loops are faster.

It seems that modern browsers have some optimizations for "normal" loops.

Firefox 13.0.1

- Normal Loop: 0.887
- Opt1: 1.025
- Opt2: 1.098
- Opt3: 1.399

Chrome 19.0.1

- Normal Loop: 3.349
- Opt1: 3.12
- Opt2: 3.109
- Opt3: 3.095

IE8

- Over 12sec...
- Repeatedly crashed during tests.

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function p(p) { console.log(p); }
// function p(p) { document.write(p); }

var testFn = function(num, niz, fn) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();

    fn(num, niz);

    var result = (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000;

    return result;
}

function normalLoop(num, niz) {
    for (var i = 0; i < niz.length; i++) {
        niz[i] = 'a' + i;
    }
}

function opt1(num, niz) {
    var len = niz.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        niz[i] = 'a' + i;
    }
}

function opt2(num, niz) {
    for (var i = niz.length; i--;) {
        niz[i] = 'a' + i;
    }
}

function opt3(num, niz) {
    while(i--) {
        niz[i] = 'a' + i;
    }
}

var niz = [];

var num = 10000000;

for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) { niz.push(i); };

p('Normal Loop: ' + testFn(num, niz, normalLoop));
p('Opt1: ' + testFn(num, niz, opt1));
p('Opt2: ' + testFn(num, niz, opt2));
p('Opt3: ' + testFn(num, niz, opt3));

</script>
```